# Handling GTK Windows in KDE4

Tags: gtk, kde4

I've installed kde via `sudo apt-get install kde-full` and it worked perfectly, and all is well, except for these ugly gtk applications. ([Pictures Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omUS9.png)) So I did some research and came across this form [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1227360) and I've installed the two packages via `sudo apt-get install kde-style-qtcurve gtk2-engines-qtcurve` and I presume that they're installed, however I cannot figure out how to do the second part :

> GTK apps look like that unless you install those and tell KDE to handle them with care, in System Settings -> Appearance -> GTK Styles and Fonts. GTK Styles, Use another style: Qtcurve. Then log out and back in.

So my question is : in KDE4 how do I accomplish the above?

Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try with the *kde-config-gtk-style* package:

**kde-config-gtk-style:**

```
 Configuration dialog to adapt GTK+ applications appearance to your taste
 under KDE. Among its many features, it lets you:
  - Choose which theme is used for GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3.x applications.
  - Tweak some GTK+ applications behaviour.
  - Select what icon theme to use in GTK+ applications.
  - Select GTK+ applications default fonts.
  - Easily browse and install new GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3.x themes.
```

- Install the package with

  `sudo apt-get install kde-config-gtk-style`
- Under **System Settings > Application Appearance** you have a new item named **"Gtk Configuration"**

[image]

- Finally you can change the options according to your needs. eg: themes, icons,fonts.

Hope this will be helpful.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

- Install engine and configuration tool

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gtk-theme-switch gtk2-engines-oxygen gtk3-engines-oxygen oxygen-molecule
  ```
- Start Theme-Switcher

  ```
  gtk-theme-switch2
  ```
- and select `oxygen-molecule` or some other gtk engine